# PhoneGap run app in landscape mode

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation

Ok, so I have a phonegap app that I'd like to run in landscape. As it is, it only runs in portrait, and nothing happens when I rotate the device (an iPad) even though the rotation is not locked.

I have:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
```

in my app-info.plist, and in the config.xml I have:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
</platform>
```

Am I missing anything? Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: you can do with xcode also, in general tab you have "device oriantation" section you can select as you required of 4 option it will done your requirements.

Comment: Also set value to 'default' into config file may help to achieve your task

Answer (score 0):

God damn it. In app-info.plist, one needs to add

```
UISupportedInterfaceOrientations
```

and add

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
```

as a parameter.